# Sound similarity of computer generated and human voice

Tags: phonetics, sound-recognition

I am looking for an algorithm to compare two sound files by means of their phonetics. I want to evaluate some kind of score (e.g. 0: no similarity; 100: the same sound). Therefore, I loaded a computer generated and a recorded human voice saying "Hello" into Audacity (I know, it's not that professional...) and looked at the waves.

https://dl.dropbox.com/s/p8o8tpsayo9xr14/hello.png (Unfortunately, I am not allowed to embed images)

Although both sound completey the same, the waves don't really match that much.

Is there a way to detect the similarity between these two waves and calculate the mentioned score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an open source project that you may be interested in [free speech recognition tools and applications](http://freespeech.sourceforge.net/). Here's another one which is an [open source toolkit for speech recognition](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/). I'm sure if you "duckduckgo" you will find others if these are not to your taste. CHEERS!